# how to correctly import an asynchronous module.exports function in javascript

Tags: javascript, async-await, node-modules

I have written an asynchronous function in a file called index.js as follows:

```
module.exports.func = async (obj) => {
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify({
        message: 'Success!',
        input: obj,
      }),
    };
};
```

However, when I try to write a test file called index.test.js, with the following code:

```
const exportedModule = require('./index');

test('Successfully execute func when empty object passed', () => {
  const obj = {};
  const expectedReturn = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify({
      message: 'Success!',
      input: obj,
    }),
  };
  const actualReturn = await exportedModule.func(obj);
  console.log(actualReturn);
  expect(actualReturn).toBe(expectedReturn);
});
```

, I get an error saying that `exportedModule.func` is not asynchronous, even through it clearly is. I cannot use promises (`.then` and `.catch`) to run the tests, as the test file will be deemed finished before the code in the `.then`/`.catch` is executed. Is there a way I'm supposed to be properly importing `func` such that I can use `await`? Ideally I would like this to be done within the test file itself without changing index.js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I get an error saying that exportedModule.func is not asynchronous

I think you're misreading the error. It's saying that the function in your *test* is not `async`. You can only use `await` in an `async` function. To fix it, add `async` to the function.

```
//                                                 added:  VVVVV
test('Successfully execute func when empty object passed', async () => {
```